# Virtual Hosts redirecting to ip address

Tags: magento-1.9.1

I have multiple domain in one ip address.One is Magento and another is normal html site.I set up virtual hosts in Nginx configuration but then only when I access to my Magento site (xxx.com) it automatically redirects to ip address.

How can I stop showing my ip address and keep my domain in the browser?

Comment: There is nothing suspicious in nginx config. Check your app. BTW, your `deny all;` directives will not work for php files in that directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config is OK. Redirect probably comes from Magento engine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But where do I check that?

Comment: Found the solution...I just had to change configuration/system/web/secure.......Thank you for your help.